# Problem with the 2nd part of the exam, please help me get to the bottom of this!

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Some parts of this exam are skipped and I need step by step explanation after the 1st line. And confirmation if result is really correct? It's from the workbook of some student and our professor gave it to us for practice and I keep getting some other number. So I wanted to check it with THE BEST OF THE BEST. I will upload a screenshot on my profile on this site https://imgbb.com/.

Thanks to anyone in advance!

I posted the image here because I don't have enoguh points :

https://ibb.co/bJxYsG

Comment: Well I guess youa re not THE BEST OF THE BEST, HERE ARE MOSTLY PEOPLE WHO CRITISIZE OTHERS AND GIVING THEM BAD RESULTS, SHAME ON YOU I'D HELP ANYONE WHO NEEDS HELP IF I COULD HELP THEM! BUT THAT'S JUST ME I GUESS!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include the question too, instead of just this answer? That might help people understand what you're asking better.

Comment: @RobertHoward English isn't my main language so it would take me to know all the right terms in english and to translate it which is very hard for me because it's not at all close to english words. The question doesn't matter, just change the numebrs I gave and try to get that J is 6,25 with step by step explanation. If it isn't what you get, then try to give me your opinion which result do you get simple as that.

Comment: I don't recognize the formula in your picture, but I plugged the values in the picture into the equation for J in the picture and got about 41,66. You can see what I did here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rij6hksmoo

Comment: @RobertHoward Oh great I also got that result! I didn't know that there is a site and that something like this is possible. Thank you very much... It's about fluid dynamics, and J is a coefficient of resistance of some valve that is blocking water flow from one picher to 2 another. Water flow is 0,023 m3/s.

Comment: Desmos is a really wonderful website - you might find it useful too! Happy I could help!

Comment: @RobertHoward Thanks. I am happy to be helped by someone like you! So you answered and resolved this, do you need to give the answer or do I need to give the answer I don't know yet how this works... I'm new here. :)

Comment: No problem! To be honest, I'm still pretty new here too. I think if you click the check mark next to the answer I just posted, that should be good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vg677nqme2

According to Desmos, $J=41.66$

Comment: That is good enough. Thanks again. :)